# Parsing python arguments in c++ extension

Tags: c++, python, python-c-api

Is there a function similar to PyArg_ParseTuple and PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords, without using a variable argument list?

I have a c++ extension that takes a long list of input arguments. Parsing them in the format of PyArg_ParseTuple and PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords is just ugly to look at. I'm hoping to be able to pass my argument list in the form of ([keyword1, format1, ptr1], [keyword2, format2, ptr2], ...). Are there existing functions or packages to do so?